# Possible to make user-specific setting changes when creating a new Windows user profile?

Tags: batch, windows-server-2008-r2, user-profiles

I'm configuring a Remote Desktop server, and each user account needs to have a predetermined but unique value set in a text (INI) file in %APPDATA% for a piece of software configuration.

I've created the necessary files and shortcuts for this to work in the C:\Users\Default profile, but would love a way to automate this INI file edit. Something like a find/replace for CHANGEME for %COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME% would be ideal, or an "append to end of file" would even work, I believe.

Is there some kind of scripting hook available for profile creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to configure a `RunOnce` script that will run the first time a local profile is created. This involves editing the registry hive for the Default profile:

1. Open `regedit.exe`
2. Load the registry hive for the default user profile into the editor

   - Click on `HKEY_USERS`
   - Go to File -> Load Hive..
   - Load `C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT` (**NOT** the `.LOG` file. It may be invisible; just type the filename manually if you have to.)
   - Give it whatever name you want; this doesn't do anything but give it a key name in the editor. For the example, we'll use "Temp"
3. Navigate to `Computer\HKEY_USERS\Temp\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`
4. Create the `RunOnce` key here if it doesn't already exist.
5. Change the string value under this key to the complete path of the executable/batch file to run.
6. Click on the Temp key again, and File -> Unload Hive...

Answer (score 1):

I would use a first logon script, a simple batch file with this in it.

`echo %COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME% >> %APPDATA%\my.ini`

Output

```
BOX\KNUCKLE-DRAGGER
```

Comment: Imagine a situation where he has to setup douzends of new users: How would he *automatically* disable that first logon script after it was executed?

Comment: Would you mind to include more details? Most users aren't aware of the `RunOnce` regkey